# How to set 'select' list in a modal dialog - Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

When I added 'Edit' function with modal dialog, I managed to set the text values. But the drop-down 'select' list not updated.

```
<template name="edit_deal">
 <button id="edit_btn" class="edit">Edit</button>
 <div id="edit_dialog" title="Edit opportunity">
  {{> Edit }}
 </div>
</template>

<template name="Edit">
 <form class="edit-deal">

    <select name="quarter">
     <option value="1">Q1</option>
     <option value="2">Q2</option>
     <option value="3">Q3</option>
     <option value="4">Q4</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="cuname" placeholder="Customer Name" >
 </form>
</template>
```

In the .js

```
Template.edit_deal.events({
 'click #edit_btn': function(event, template) {
  $( "#edit_dialog" ).dialog('open');

  Deals.find({"_id" : this._id}).fetch();

  $('input[name="quarter"]').val(this.quarter);
  $('input[name="cuname"]').val(this.customerName);
 }
});
```

When the 'Edit' modal dialog pops up, all values updates but the 'select' list. What is missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're searching for an input tag with this line:

```
$('input[name="quarter"]').val(this.quarter);
```

Look for a select instead:

```
$('select[name="quarter"]').val(this.quarter);
```

Comment: Shame on me... You are absolutely right. Thank you!